# Windows Server 3 or 4 Disk Parity Configuration

Tags: raid, hard-drive, windows-server-2016, storage-spaces

right now I've got an Ubuntu Server with a 3x4TB Software Raid 5 Configuration.

I came to the conclusion, that the best for me would be to switch to Windows Server.

I also researched that RAID 5 configurations shouldn't be used anymore due there is no parity during rebuilding.

Right now, I'm unsure how I should arrange my disks in the Future Windows Environment.

I concluded to several options:

- Storage Spaces in parity mode (should be similar to RAID 5 with single parity only, should have bad performance)
- Buying a 4th Disk and using Storage Spaces in mirror mode (should be similar to RAID 10 or 01)
- Buying a 4th Disk and arranging a Raid 10 with the onboard Raid Controller (it's an HP Microserver Gen8)

What would be the best choice? or even another option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stick with raid 5 unless you have a *real* reason not to.  Having a second disk fail during rebuild is *likely* to result in total failure with raid10 as well, so that isn't really helping you there.  And always remember that raid is no substitute for backups.

Comment: I can't stick with (software) raid 5 because I have a Linux raid with mdadm and I'm switching to windows, which doesn't support Linux raid

Comment: Yea, so use the hardware one, or Windows software raid5.

Comment: I would suggest to use hardware RAID10 for better performance and resiliency. Check out this links: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/95f6e174-3625-48ae-8cc9-f19a65a909b5/storage-spaces-vs-raid-am-i-missing-something?forum=winserverfiles
https://serverfault.com/questions/685289/software-vs-hardware-raid-performance-and-cache-usage

Comment: Sorry but psusi is utterly wrong about using R5 - R5 is dead technology, and has been for the best part of a decade, pro's don't use it and wouldn't dream of using it on large disks - if you love your data please don't use R5 - R1/10 and R6/60 are the only games in town (or RAID-Z if your a ZFS kinda-guy)

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to Windows, you can boldly use onboard HP Raid controller to build Raid 10 and get a stable, reliable configuration.